# Info.plist not in correct format

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, info-plist

I was working through my iOS Xcode project just fine, and then all of a sudden when I tried to run it, I started getting the error below:

```
error: couldn't parse contents of '/Users/pavitarsidhu/Desktop/AmigoDash/SidebarDemo/AmigoDash-Info.plist': The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

I'm really confused. I've looked at the past StackOverflow questions and still have not been able to fix this. Is there anyway to just generate a new infoplist? What do you guys think?

Comment: Sometimes this happens if you have a merge conflict in this file from source control.  In that case, open the file in a plain text editor and look for the markings from source control, which usually start with "<<<<<<<<<<" and end with ">>>>>>>>>>>>>"

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `info.plist`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A plist file is an XML document in a tightly specified format; both XML and the Property List structure have very strict rules. You can easily mess things up by accident if you attempt to edit the info.plist manually (i.e., as text) by saying Open As > Source Code:

[image]

You are unlikely to get this format right. Thus, you should always edit the info.plist with Open As > Property List:

[image]

This allows the property list editor to generate the XML for you, and it is unlikely to make a mistake in the resulting XML structure. Of course I suppose you *could* still mess up the value of something...

Comment: *You are unlikely to get this format right*, what would be considered correct XML formatting?

Comment: The issue with the property list editor is the inability to add in comments. At least I've found no way to add a comment to explain why some of the more esoteric settings are made.  You just need to be very careful to have struct open/close tag structure - I just spend an hour fighting this because I moved a section down via copy/paste but then did not delete one of the moved lines which resulted in an imbalance and more Xcode "Seriously!?" frustration.

Comment: This can happen even if you change a variable name eg: from string to String.

Comment: It happend to me due to a commited merge conflict -.-

Comment: Is this a correct answer? Maybe is the reason but not the solution

Comment: @Leemur Well, the OP didn't show the _Info.plist_ contents so it's impossible to pinpoint the error within it. And the answer was accepted, suggesting that it set the OP on the correct path.

Comment: Of course, but I don't feel that like an answer. Maybe is possible that the file type is not set as Information Property List, even if the content is Ok.

Answer (score 25):

I encountered the same error. Took quite a while to figure it out. Here's how I did it:

- Go to your terminal
- Navigate to the location where the `plist` file is located e.g `cd /user/desktop/app/Runner/info.plist`
- Then use the `plutil` command like so `plutil info.plist`

This will show you where the error is and you can go about correcting it. I hope that helps.

Comment: agree - this is the most helpful solution for many potential problems. My latest - empty <integer> on line 2587.

Comment: This should be the correct/best answer.  It took seconds to find the error in my 2000 line plist file that I had already spent 20 minutes going through line by line to find the problem.  My plist file is an employee directory that is auto-generated from a database and it was missing a string value for one of the keys.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same issue and it was because plist files do not like `&`. You have to use `&amp;` instead of an ampersand.

Comment: You saved me a few hours.

Answer (score 4):

I had a merge conflict and didn't realize it so there were git annotations in the file. I couldn't open it as a property list but I opened as source code and fixed the issue that way.