# Malformed InfoPlist.strings file

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode8

My app upload to the App Store failed with reason:

> "Malformed InfoPlist.strings file - The file is not in the proper
>   format."

My InfoPlist.strings file is 121 bytes in size and it contains only two strings. When I dig into the app files inside the Xcode archive file, I see it is converted to a binary file. This binary file differs from the same binary file from a successfully uploaded previous version of my app, though there are no changes made to InfoPlist.strings file between these two versions.

I managed to workaround the problem by manually replacing the invalid binary file with the proper one in the Xcode archive and then submitting that archive to the App Store from Xcode.

I don't want to perform this manual step on each app release though. I could not find the reason for the malformed strings file in my code. I'm using Xcode 8.3.1 and it just started to produce that malformed file. I reverted all the changes to all of my app files till a version that used to generate a valid strings file, yet Xcode produces a malformed one now.

I wonder if anybody managed to fix this problem.

Comment: you should refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30814782/1308632

Comment: same problem here, any workaround?

Comment: I managed to workaround it by editing the source plist.strings file

Comment: @VladimirGrigorov but we are `InfoPlist.strings` file. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: In my case 1 of my target was having 2 `InfoPlist.strings` files, they were formatted properly. So removing 1 `InfoPlist.strings` file worked for me.